# How to sort By Name and status Active for JPA repository query?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.2

I am developing **Spring Boot + Spring Data JPA + Postgres + Lombok** example. In this example, I want to fetch all student firstName is ASC order and whose status in `Active`.

I developed below query, which works fine, but I don't see a way to also use `status=Active` here in `JpaRepository` query.

Note: In my case, `status` field is `Enum` in Java.

Is there any way if we can do the same? I know I can fetch all students and then using streams can easily filter, but using JpaRepository query, is there any way?

```
List<Student> students = studentRepository.findAll(new Sort(Sort.Direction.ASC, "studentName"));
```

Comment: you can do this findAllByStatusOrderByStudentNameAsc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `StudentRepository` interface, that extends `Repository / JpaRepository` you can add a method signature like that:

```
public interface StudentRepository extends ....{
  List<Student> findAllByStatusOrderByStudentNameAsc(String status);
}
```

Comment: Isn't this the same answer posted by me.

Comment: It seems you were actually 1 minute later.

Comment: @Johna I wrote my answer at the same time as you and submitted if a few seconds after you. I'll give your answer a vote up.

Comment: @riorio I understood it friend. No competition here, if he found the answer to his problem, that's it.

Comment: And where would be the actual function can be found?

Answer (score 1):

Just put the following method signature in your repository and call it where you need with argument 'Active'.

```
List<Student> findAllByStatusOrderByStudentNameAsc(String status);
```